# Image field upload shows a broken preview until I reload the page

Tags: 7, media

When I upload an image it does an AJAX upload and then tries to show the thumbnail but the thumbnail style of that image is not available, so it shows up as a missing image. If I save and come back to the form, then it displays fine.

Comment: Please compare paths in both cases and check the difference?

Comment: The paths are identical

Comment: the image does not exist until the entity is saved

Comment: Have you tried `sudo chmod -R 777 files/`?

Answer (score 1):

make sure the "image style" of your image field exists. for example to make sure about our "Article" content type, we check the path below:

> http://yoursite.com/admin/structure/types/manage/article/fields/field_image

find your "image style" name and then go the path below:

> http://yoursite.com/admin/config/media/image-styles

check the image styles name and make sure "Article" image style is here. if it's not, you have to change image style of your content type.